# Poisson regression residual analysis

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution, residuals, contingency-tables

In a three factor poisson (log-linear) model $(A*B*C)$, when the highest interaction term $(A:B:C)$ is dropped, the response/raw residuals are exactly the same for different levels of two of the factors but with opposite signs i.e. in a $3\times3$ contingency table, all rows have same residuals with alternating signs but the columns are different. Is there a reason to them being identical?

For example on pg. 29 of the following, in the raw residuals column we can see the pattern repeat but with opposite signs. Is this simply because of double interactions, if so why?

http://www.ncss.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/NCSS/Poisson_Regression.pdf

Comment: What do you mean by "pg.35-29"? I skimmed the pages from 29 through 35, & I don't see what you're referring to.

Comment: Hi, apologies for the typo, it is on page 29 'Residuals Section', in the raw residual column. This is the pattern: -6.6998 -4.0638 3.5850 4.3026 -4.8263 7.7021 6.6998 4.0638 -3.5850 -4.3026 4.8263 -7.7021